# Automate Permission Request from Access Denied Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, access-denied

SharePoint Developers,
I have been tasked with a new project and could use some suggestions as how best to...
Project requirements:

1. User gets access denied page. (we do not use the *SharePoint Request Access* we use AD groups). 
    I am thinking add a link on the Access Denied page to a form. Editing as noted here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31253.sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-custom-access-denied-page.aspx.
2. Provide user a form to select the level of permissions from the AD Group permissions available on the site. *(usually view, contribute or designer)*. We use AD Groups for site permissions. The form would also include a text area to specify why they need access. I would need to grab the AD Groups for the site and the site URL from SharePoint.
3. Then pass the logged in userID, the AD Group for the selected level of permissions, the site URL and the text area data to a stored procedure used by a permissions provisioning tool.

Has anyone built anything like this before? ***I am having trouble figuring out how to grab the AD groups assigned to the sites permissions and the site URL from SharePoint?*** Once I have that it should be fairly simple to pass the selected values from the form. Any suggestions or ideas on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This article is doing this all without Visual Studios, but I'd develop something in visual studios and add some code behind to grab the current user `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser` and use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` to add that user to the correct AD group based on a user's selection.

Comment: I have replaced the existing AccessDenied.ASPX with a Custom page. So that piece works. I have worked in Visual Studio (Asp.net and C#) but not quite sure how to apply in SharePoint.
So I guess that is what I need to figure out. How do I setup the environment to build this and deploy to SharePoint 2013.